# Create a TFS alert rule that triggers when a field is changed from a non-blank value?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a TFS alert for when a field is changed in a work item only when it's a non-blank value? Basically, I'd like the negation of 'When changes from ""'

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it's not able to achieve this through built-in Alert filters. Since we do not have a symbol which stands for  `a non-blank value`

If there are not so many specified values for that Filed, you could add multiple alert filters and with `or` which may do the trick, kind like below:

```
And Design Target Changes from Value1

  or Design Target Changes from Value2

     or Design Target Changes from Value3
                .....
```

Otherwise, you may do this through a server side event handler to achieve this.

- Intercept the Work Item changed event
- Check if the change was a
  change in state
- If it is, then email the address listed in the
  Requester field.

There are couple of old projects on codeplex which should get you up and running but you'll need to update for newly TFS version (and test with any updates you apply later)

[Email alerts for TFS](https://tfsemailalert.codeplex.com/)

[TFS Work Item Watcher](https://tfswiwatcher.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the followup. Unfortunately, the field will contain a date, so it could be any number of values. I'll look at doing this with a webhook instead. Thanks!